# Lightning Datatable - Hide actions for specific rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have an LWC consisting of a datatable. I am using a wrapper class to get `Accounts` and `Contacts` and display them using datatable. I have `edit` and `delete` action for each row. I want to hide the action button for `Contacts` (contacts should not be allowed to be edited or deleted). `Accounts` rows should have the action button.

Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe a rendered attribute? Any help is appreciated.

---

### Screenshot of LWC

[image: Remove action for contact records]

---

### Javascript

```js
const actions = [
    { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' },
];

const columns = [
    {
        type: 'action',
        typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions },
    },
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Api Name', type: 'button', typeAttributes: { label:  {fieldName: 'apiName'}, variant: 'base' } },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', type: 'email' },
];

export default class ContactRelatedAddress extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track columns = columns;
    @track addresses;
    refreshTable;

    @wire(getAddress, { id: '$recordId' }) wired(result) {
        this.refreshTable = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.addresses = result.data;
        }
        if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### HTML

```html
<lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={addresses} columns={columns} onrowaction={handleRowActions}
                hide-checkbox-column="true">
</lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just tested it. it works fine for me. I have used the **cellAttributes** property to assign a css class to each cell of the action column:

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={addresses} columns={columns} hide-checkbox-column="true">
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import  { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import cssResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/CssFile';

const actions = [
    { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' },
];

export default class HideAction extends LightningElement {

    @track addresses = [
                        {Id:1, name: 'Accedo-10001681', email: 'test@gmail.com', apiName: 'Account', cssClass: 'showActionButton'},
                        {Id:2, name: 'A Call To Action Medi..', email: 'test@gmail.com', apiName: 'Account', cssClass: 'showActionButton'},
                        {Id:3, name: 'Adam Baxter', email: 'adam.baxter@gmail.com', apiName: 'Contact', cssClass: 'hideActionButton'},
                        {Id:4, name: 'Adam Aigner-Treworgy', email: 'adamat@gmail.com', apiName: 'Contact', cssClass: 'hideActionButton'}                 
                      ];

    actions = [
                { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit' },
                { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' },
              ];

    @track columns = [
        { label: 'Actions', type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions , menuAlignment: 'left'}, cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'cssClass' }}},
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', type: 'text'},
        { label: 'Api Name', type: 'button', typeAttributes: { label:  {fieldName: 'apiName'}, variant: 'base' } },
        { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', type: 'email' },
    ];

    connectedCallback(){
        loadStyle(this, cssResource);
    }


}
```

and add the string property **cssClass** in your wrapper class. You can use **hideActionButton** and **showActionButton** as values of the cssClass property.

Finally, you have to create a css file as a static resource otherwise it will not work. Put into the css static resource this code bellow to hide the action button:

```
.hideActionButton{
    opacity: 0; 
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is a [link](https://hellosnl.blogspot.com/2019/07/lwc-override-css-of-standard-lightning-components.html) showing how to override css of standard lwc components

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the cell borders as it is in Datatable, Then Try the following  CSS.

**Instead of this:**

```
 .hideActionButton{
    opacity: 0; 
}
```

**Try This:**

```
.hideActionButton .slds-dropdown-trigger.slds-dropdown-trigger_click {
   display: none;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]